# 'operator =' is ambiguous for std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a class with my own cast operators but I am having issues with multiple `operator=`s

I managed to reproduce the issue with the small code below

```
#include <string>

class X
{
public:
  operator const char*() const {
    return "a";
  }
  operator std::string() {
    return "c";
  }
};

void func( )
{
  X x;
  std::string s = "";
  s = x;
}
```

I understand that `std::basic_string` has multiple assignment operator and this is why the compiler gets confused.

If I remove either cast operators it works, but I was wondering if there was a way of keeping both operators.

My class will be returning different values depending on the cast.

I could also use `static_cast<std::string>(x)` to force the cast, but I was wondering if there was a a way of doing it without the static cast?

Comment: How about `s = std::string(x)`?

Comment: Yeah, a cast would work, (as mentioned in my post), but my question is more if I could hint to the compiler what to use so that I don't need to use a cast itself.

Comment: Isn't the cast exactly a "hint to the compiler"?

Comment: Yes, of course, you are correct, but I think you understand what I mean.
if `s` is defined as a `std::string` I would like the compiler to use the `operator std::string()` without the need of a cast

Comment: The problem is that `std::string` has two matching constructors, and there's no rule in the language giving the copy constructor priority over the other one. No way to impose one either that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

As KerrekSB [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926180/operator-is-ambiguous-for-stdstring/39926203#comment67135954_39926180), you can use

```
s = std::string(x);
```

Alternatively, you can perform a cast:

```
s = (std::string) x;
// or
s = static_cast<std::string>(x);
```

A third alternative (which I would hope not to see in the wild very often due to readability concerns) is to access the operator directly:

```
s = x.operator std::string();
```

---

If you're willing to make the tradeoff of a slightly different API (and fixing any potential breakages) you can do what Roberto [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926241/510036) and force the explicit casting of *just* the `const char *` type operator:

```
class X
{
public:
  explicit operator const char*() const {
    return "a";
  }
  operator std::string() {
    return "c";
  }
};
```

This tells the compiler to only allow *implicit* conversions to `std::string`, and requires you do explicitly cast to `const char *` when you want to invoke that particular operator.

---

One last thing to note: if you are designing other classes or methods that would consume this particular class, another thing to try is to reverse the way they're used by providing an overload for `class X` rather than converting `X` to something else.

Always good to consider alternative ways for your API to work.

Comment: Formally, `std::string(x)` is also a *cast* (written in functional notation).

Comment: @AnT `std::string(x)` invokes a constructor and doesn't perform an actual cast -- the compiler might optimize this down, sure, but semantically that's not what's happening.

Comment: So? `(std::string) x` also invokes a constructor. And yes, `std::string(x)` is a cast, exactly as it is defined in the language standard. A *cast* is a purely syntactic element of the language. Semantics of a cast boils down to semantics of type conversion. The latter depends on the types involved. The language actually explicitly says that a functional-notation cast with a single argument is equivalent to classic cast-notation cast with the same argument. I.e. `std::string(x)` cast is defined as equivalent to `(std::string) x` cast.

Comment: Moreover, in C++ `std::string()` and `std::string(20, ' ')` are also *casts* expressed through the very same *functional notation*, even though they have zero or more than one argument inside the `()`. The fact that they invoke constructors is just how these the casts are required to work in C++. Constructor invocation does not in any way contradict the concept of a *cast*. As another relevant note, the effect of basic `static_cast<T>(e)` in C++ is also defined through initialization `T t(e)`, i.e. constructor invocation in case of a class types.

Comment: For which reason it is not clear to me what your "semantically that's not what's happening" remark is supposed to mean. What do you believe should happen semantically for a cast to be a cast? And how can that (whatever that is) possibly help to differentiate between `(std::string) x` and `std::string(x)`, when the language standard defines these two forms as equivalent?

Comment: @AnT could you point to the section of the spec that defines constructors as casts?

Comment: There's no section that "defines constructors as casts". There's **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]** which defines all variants of `SomeType(...)` syntax (with any number of parameters inside `()`) as explicit type conversion. "Constructor invocation" is just one possible particular consequence of that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `explicit` keyword on char* cast you'll default casting to std::string.

```
class X
{
public:
    explicit operator const char*() const {
        return "a";
    }
    operator std::string() {
         return "c";
    }
};
```

after it your casts:

```
X x;
std::string s = "";
s = x;
```

will succeed (and the user of your class will need to specify char* cast if he wants to use the other cast)

Any way, as a user of your class I would rather prefer if both castings are explicit, so I know when a casting is being made

Comment: This is also a great alternative, though it changes the semantics of your API slightly and may introduce code breakage (it may be a good tradeoff, though). Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: You are right @Qix, I prefer both casts being explicit, but I think Simon should decide that

Comment: `const char *c = x;` won't work anymore this way. You are simpl breaking the api the other way around.

Comment: @skypjack hence my comment.